# How to call a function in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the a function that receives two dates and returns the weekdays between the dates.

```
int WeekDayBetweenDates(DateTime firstDate, DateTime secondDate)
```

I wanted to call this function in a Linq I'm making where if I get a certain country then I need to check the dates if they're enrollment date is 5 weekdays from today.

Say for example I have a list of user.

```
List<users> userList = getUsers();

public class user
{
   string Name;
   string Country;
   DateTime EnrollmentDate;
}
```

So I created a function that extracts the users that are not 5 weekdays away from today for their Enrollment date and are from Canada

```
List<users> extract unQualifiedUsers(List<user> uList)
{
 List<user> uqUserList = new List<list>();

 uqUserList  = uList.Where(u=> u.Country == "Canada" && WeekDayBetweenDates(u.EnrollmentDate, DateTime.Now) > 5).ToList();

uList = uList.Except(uqUserList ).toList();

return uqUserList;
}
```

However, after doing this I encountered and error. Should I just loop through every single user from Canada and get them? Or is there a way to call my custom method in a linQ?

Comment: What is the error you get? The code you have included does not compile.

Comment: I see at least 3 compiler errors: 1) `Where` should be capitalized, 2) You are trying to assign an `IEnumerable<user>` to a variable declared as `List<user>`, 3) you do not have a `return` statement (just reassigning the input parameter variable).

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated the code and their doesn't seem to be any other error other than the one you've pointed out.

Comment: Your updated code still wouldn't compile. Why are you posting non-compiling code? And your code is a mess, fix your intention etc. so it looks good for people trying to read it to help you.

Comment: Where is your `getUser`-method?

Comment: @GashioLee You did not fix error #2.

Comment: Jelle Kerkstra: getUser is not important in this question; the only thing you need to know is that the input parameter of method unQualifiedUsers is a `List<User>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this code is incorrect:

```
List<users> userList = getUsers();

public class user
{
   string Name;
   string Country;
   DateTime EnrollmentDate;
}
```

`List<users>` should be `List<user>`. Next to that, the `Name`, `Country` and `EnrollmentDate` should be marked `public` in order to be accessed.

The same goes for the return type of the `extract unQualifiedUsers`-method (which is invalid because a method name cannot contain any spaces.

`List<user> uqUserList = new List<list>();` doesn't compile either because you are trying to make a List of list (?). `List<user> uqUserList = new List<user>();` will work.

The line `uList = uList.Except(uqUserList).toList();` is redundant because the `.Where` already does the filtering (and it is incorrect code. `ToList` has a capital T.

And at last, your filtering logic is incorrect. You want all the users that have been enrolled for less than 5 days.

Fixing all these issues, would result in the following code:

```
List<user> extractunQualifiedUsers(List<user> uList)
{
    return uList.Where(u => u.Country == "Canada" && WeekDayBetweenDates(u.EnrollmentDate, DateTime.Now) < 5).ToList();
}


public class user
{
    public string Name;
    public string Country;
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate;
}
```

Piece of advice: Get your code to compile first! Code that does not compile or is not complete/testable will almost invariably be received negatively here on SO. [This Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a very good resource on how to write good questions.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a country name and a sequence of users.

You want all users that live in that country and have an EnrollmentDate that is between now and 5 days from now.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
string country = ...
IEnumerable<User> users = ...
var result = users.Where(user => user.Country == country
                              && WeekdayBetweenDates(now, user.EnrollmentDate) < 5);
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Answer (score -5):

```
uqUserList  = uList.where(u=> { return u.Country == "Canada" && WeekDayBetweenDates(u.EnrollmentDate, DateTime.Now) });
```

You just needed simply using curly brackets to wrap the code.
By using this, you may write any code that return correct variable.

Example in this linq using where clause, it must return boolean type variable.

Comment: No braces or `return` are needed here, as the lambda body contains only a single expression.

Comment: `WeekDayBetweenDates` returns a integer, not a boolean! Braces and return are also redundant